# MySQL 404 error, php file not found

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I'm trying to create a text box for users to enter their emails and insert them into the database. 
And I have the following files:

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="sql.php">
    Email Address:
    <input name="email" type="text" required placeholder="Enter A Valid Email Address">
    <button type ="submit" name="submit" value="send"> SEND </button>
</form>
```

sql.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $email=$_POST['email'];
        mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
        $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO mytable (email) VALUES ('$email')";

        if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
            die('error inserting new record');
        }
        $newrecord = "1 record added to database";
    }
?>
```

When I hit the submit button, I get the error:

> "POST /sql.php" Error (404): "Not found"

I have doubled checked to make sure that both files are in the same directory, the php file DOES exist, I also tried changing `action="sql.php"` to `action="/sql.php"`. I really couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Where is your index.html and  sql.php[path]

Comment: Your web server can't find sql.php .  Maybe it's in a special folder away from your index file?

Comment: check both file should be in same folder and check php file extension some times there will be a hidden extension

Comment: What kind of server are you using to test your site? MAMP?

Comment: run your file in browser url then make sure what your action file path

Comment: @RushilPachchigar /dev/myProject/index.html and /dev/myProject/sql.php

Comment: @magreenberg I'm using the command-line http server

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run your files on localhost and it is working fine for me. There is possibility of two things in your case

File extension :Maker user your file extension is fine it should be sql.php instead of sql.php.txt etc

You are testing your code at server i.e `http://localhost/test/index.html` instead of directly open file in browser

Comment: Is the .txt part hidden? Also, do you think it might be the server I'm using that's causing the problem?

Comment: @teresal yes .txt part might be hidden

Answer (score -1):

Replace `<button type ="submit" name="submit" value="send"> SEND </button>` to `<input type ="submit" name="submit" value="SEND">`

I think this should work. Please try

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: There is a difference:

<input type="button" /> buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

<input type="submit"> buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

Comment: OP is using `<button type="submit">` which, last I checked, will submit the form just like `<input type="submit">`. In fact I know it is because *how else would OP be getting to /sql.php in the first place?*

Answer (score -1):

Its better to define a constant for root.

```
define('WWW', 'http://www.domain.com/');
```

and update your HTML

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo WWW;?>sql.php">
```

Now if you html and sql.php files are on same level, it will work fine.

otherwise you can add folder address in

like

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo WWW;?>folder/sql.php">
```

Comment: Have you not heard of "relative URLs"?

Comment: Yes I heard. But is not that a solution ? 
if no then update with correct answer :)